# Using Vector3.Distance for an A* heuristic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, a-star

I am trying to develop a path finding system in Unity using a * search.
I'm trying to understand this function to calculate the f cost.

f(n) = h(n) + c(n,m)

I have read that the heuristic function gives an estimate of the minimum cost from any vertex n to the goal. Can I use Vector3.Distance for this? If this a suitable way to get the h(n) value?

And then c would the cost of moving from the start node to this node calculated by added the distance between the nodes incrementally?

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right.